# Bash complains about syntax errors in here-document when using backticks

Tags: bash, cat, quoting, backticks

I'm running the following piece of bash code:

```
cat << END_TEXT
       _             _ 
      | |           | |
  __ _| |__   ___ __| |
 / _` | '_ \ / __/ _` |
| (_| | |_) | (_| (_| |
 \__,_|_.__/ \___\__,_|
END_TEXT
```

and am getting an error:

```
bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
bash: command substitution: line 1: ` | '_ \ / __/ _'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to escape backticks. Just use quoted here-doc string as:

```
cat <<-'END_TEXT'
        _             _
       | |           | |
   __ _| |__   ___ __| |
  / _` | '_ \ / __/ _` |
 | (_| | |_) | (_| (_| |
  \__,_|_.__/ \___\__,_|
END_TEXT
```

As per `man bash`:

> If word is **unquoted**, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the character sequence `\<newline>` is ignored, and `\`  must  be  used  to quote the characters `\`, `$`, and `` ` ``.

Comment: A better solution than mine, awesome.

Answer (score 1):

It's the backticks. Most content in a here-document is not intrepreted and used as-is, but backticks change this.

The solution: Escape them, even though it messes up the layout of your script:

```
cat << END_TEXT
       _             _ 
      | |           | |
  __ _| |__   ___ __| |
 / _\` | '_ \ / __/ _\` |
| (_| | |_) | (_| (_| |
 \__,_|_.__/ \___\__,_|
END_TEXT
```